# Bind ready event on javascript dom element creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to know if we can bind a loaded or ready event on an item created by a script when the dom is loaded. I heard from live() but it's not something clickable, it's just an item which has to load.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I guess your best shot is the `load` event there.

```
$('element').load(function(){
   alert('loaded');
});
```

native

```
var elem = document.getElementById('element_id');
elem.onload = function(){
   alert('loaded');
};
```

Another example for dynamic creation:

```
$('<img/>', {
   src:   '/images/myimage.png',
   load:  function(){
     alert('image loaded');
   }
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to separate the pieces of code for creating the item and the load event handling you could try having your dynamically created element trigger a custom event on the window:

```
var myElement = $('<img/>', {
   src:   '/images/myimage.png'
}).appendTo(document.body);

$(window).trigger( {type: "myElementInit", myObject : myElement} );
```

With a pointer back to itself in the extra parameters, you could then have a separate handler set-up within a jQuery(document).ready to look for the "myElementInit" window event and grab the reference to the element out of the extra parameters:

```
jQuery.('window').bind( "myElementInit", function(event){
  var theElement = event.myObject;
...
} );
```

Comment: As said before my problem is that i can't edit the parent item.

Comment: not sure I understand then.  can you post some code snippet?  what did you mean "I heard from live()"?

Comment: I can't post some code.
1/ I've got a script that i can't modify adding a div in the dom when the document is ready.
2/ I've got my script which is adding an other div in the dom and which need to be created after the div created in 1/ has been really added to the DOM

Is that much clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegated form of the `.on()` event, as [documented here](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or `document` if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   `document` element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.