# Access and use $.post results easily?

Tags: jquery, draggable, .post

Im trying to create a page in which users can search for items on the left side of the page, and drag and drop the items they want onto the right, kind of like a shopping cart.

I have been using

```
 $(function() {
 $(".result").draggable({
    helper: function(event, ui) {
    return $(this).clone().children("img");
    }
    });

    $("#rightcol").droppable({
        accept: ".result",
        drop: function(event,ui){
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        //console.log($(ui.draggable));
        }
        });

});
```

for the drag & drop which works how I was hoping for, but whatever the user drags onto the the right side (#rightcol) is lost when a new search is submitted. I have tried changing the form submit to use ajax with jquery like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#form").submit( function () {    
          $.post(
           'p_search.php',
            $(this).serialize(),
          function(data){
              //data is what i want to be draggable
              //call other function here
              $(".build").html(data).load();
            }
          );
          return false;   
        });   

 });
```

Which works great, but the divs(.result) are not draggable. Is there a way to easily initialize the (.result) elements without refreshing the page?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events

Comment: thanks, i didn't see this one, I think liveDraggable is just what I was looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they're not draggable because they were created **after** you've defined which items are draggable.
(meaning - they're created after the `$(".result").draggable(...` call.)
I think you should take a look at [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: `.live()` handles events, not initialisation of new objects per se.

Comment: @Orbling: you're right. suggestions here may be worth looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494293/bind-ready-event-on-javascript-dom-element-creation. The highest-voted answer to the question you've linked to also provides a seemingly very good and elegant solution.

Comment: I've tried live but wasn't able to get it to work like i was hoping, Im pretty new to jquery but i think i just need to name the drag function, and call it in function(data)

Comment: have you tried plugging into the `load` event-  `$(".result").live('load', function() {...});`? can you explain what isn't working?